# How to create face between plane and cylinder objects?

Tags: faces

Creating a 3D model of a vehicle, so I need to create faces between cylinder and plane object in order to form a fender of the car. Every time when I try to press F on my keyboard or select "New Edge/Face from Vertices", the command does not work. Please help me to fix this!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those vertices belong to two different objects.
You need to join the objects into one, before you connect the vertices.

*Object > Join*, <kbd>Ctrl + J</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! It worked!

Comment: @NarimanMergalym Please don't add thank you as an answer, upvote the answer instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted